# Is there a way to have a confirmation of the message going through in an RPC procedure RabbitMQ? NodeJS

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, jobs, rpc

I'm learning to use Rabbit and I'm not very familiar yet with it. I was doing some testing because I need to send a job request to a queue and when the consumer finishes the process I need the answer back. I saw the RPC procedure in the Rabbit documentation and I implemented it in my code. I saw that if the consumer has an error the client still waits for an answer on the exclusive queue and doesn't close the connection. So I found some documentation about the confirmed channel and created a callback on my sendToQueue method, that when the msg is asked, it will consume the reply. But it seems to give me no error even if I nack the answer, deleting the message from the queue. I need to check for errors cause the server side needs to do a long procedure, so if anything goes wrong I don't know how to inform the client that the consumer has raised some error or that the message for some reason is nacked. I tried to publish with a callback, but I don't think it was the right answer.

**Sending the request**

```
const amqp = require("amqplib");
const { v4 } = require("uuid");

const args = process.argv.slice(2);
const id = v4();
console.log(args);

const time = args[0].split(",")[3];

if (args.length == 0) {
  process.exit(1);
}

const connect = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await amqp.connect(process.env.MQSERVER_URL);
    console.log("connessione creata");
    //const chann = await conn.createChannel();
    const chann = await conn.createConfirmChannel();
    console.log("canale creato");
    await chann.checkQueue(process.env.QNAME);

    const q = await chann.assertQueue("", { exclusive: true });

    chann.sendToQueue(
      process.env.QNAME,
      Buffer.from(args.toString()),
      {
        replyTo: q.queue,
        correlationId: id,
      },
      (err) => {
        if (err !== null) {
          chann.consume(q.queue, (msg) => {
            console.log(msg);
            if (msg.properties.correlationId == id) {
              console.log(
                "La risposta del messaggio è ---->",
                msg.content.toString()
              );
              setTimeout(() => {
                conn.close();
              }, 500);
            } else {
              console.log("ERROR");
              conn.close();
            }
          });
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("ERROR -->", err);
  }
};
  connect();
```

**Consumer**

```
const amqp = require("amqplib");

let url = "amqp://localhost:5672";
let q = "trial";

function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

const connection = async () => {
  try {
    console.log("starting connection");
    const conn = await amqp.connect(url);
    const chann = await conn.createChannel();

    await chann.assertQueue(q, { durable: false });
    console.log("Aspettando messaggi...");
    console.log("-------------------------");
    chann.prefetch(1);
    chann.consume(
      q,
      async (msg) => {
        console.log("elaborando");
        const arr = msg.content.toString().split(",");
        await wait(5000);
        let res;
        switch (arr[0]) {
          case "sum":
            res = parseInt(arr[1]) + parseInt(arr[2]);
            break;
          case "multiply":
            res = parseInt(arr[1]) * parseInt(arr[2]);
            break;
        }
        console.log(res);
        console.log("Inviando con id->", msg.properties.correlationId);
        if (!res) {
          chann.nack(msg, false, false);
        } else {
          chann.sendToQueue(
            msg.properties.replyTo,
            Buffer.from(res.toString()),
            {
              correlationId: msg.properties.correlationId,
            }
          );
        }
      },
      { noAck: false }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("X ------> ERRORE", err);
  }
};

connection();
```

An example of what I need is:

1. The user asks for a pdf
2. BE takes some data and creates a unique name for a file
3. Everything is sent to the queue
4. Consumers wait in that queue take the data and create a pdf
5. After he finished it gives the ok to the client
6. The client consumes on the exclusive channel we gave on reply-to
7. The client saves the pdf

The procedure to create a pdf could be long so I need and need many data, so if something is missing I need to create an error to communicate to the client side.

An Alt path would be:

1. The user asks for a pdf
2. BE takes some data and creates a unique name for a file
3. Everything is sent to the queue
4. Consumers wait on that queue take the data and create a pdf
5. Some data are missing, nacking the message and giving an error back
6. The client set the request status to Failed